# Unicode escaping encoding technique gives this as an output. Why?

Tags: python-3.x, hex, byte, unicode-escapes

I have written a python read script which has the following code`

```
def read_serial():
    while True:
        # prepare for response
        out = ''
        while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            out += ser.read(1).decode('unicode_escape')

        if out != '':
            response_header = out.encode('unicode_escape').strip()
            print( "Response recieved " ,response_header)
            print((response_header[0],response_header[1],response_header[2])) //line 2
```

So the bytes array that I'm sending is:

```
data[] = {0x9c,0x10,0x01,0x05,0x07,0x08};
```

and on python side..in line 2 I'm receiving this:

```
Response recieved  b'\\\x9c\\\x10\\\x01\\\x05\\\x07\\\x08'
(92, 120, 57)
```

Why 92,120,57 what does this mean because for 9C decimal would be 156?

Any suggestions? Or which encoding technique you suggest for bytes?

Comment: You are encoding as Unicode escapes, so (92,120,57) are the ASCII codes for backslash, `x` and 9.  I assume you are doing that on the sending side also to need the decode.  Skip encode/decode and just send bytes.

Comment: When I do it without any encoding technique..For byte above 126 for example 0xab..I receive this error..UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xab in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: If sending data bytes, you don't need encoding at all.  `send(bytes([0x9c,0x10,0x01,0x05,0x07,0x08]))`.  Actually show your send and recv code if you want more help.

Comment: @Mark I'm sending from arduino

Comment: `out = b''` and `out += ser.read(1)` then.  Just receive the byte.  No decoding required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just receive the bytes.  Something like this since I can't run your code:

```py
def read_serial():
    while True:
        # prepare for response
        out = b''   # bytes type
        while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            out += ser.read(1)

        if out != b'':
            print("Response received:",out.hex())
```